# Rating star field in a material ui/redux-form framework not setting to blank on double click of value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I am working on a react website - with a form frame that uses material ui and redux forms ---

I've added a rating field -- and it works well - when you click on the same value it will clear the stars - but when I click off the field it returns the old value back --- I've tried to do all sorts from if(type of input.value === string) -- convert to 0 -- and tried to parseFloat on inputchanges -- but I am not sure what is causing the bug

its using the controlled rating - https://material-ui.com/components/rating/

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-grass-ccg69

```
  <Rating
    {...input}
    name={input.name + "-" + uuid()}
    onChange={(e, value) => {
      input.onChange(value);
      onHandle(input.name, value);
    }}
    value={parseFloat(input.value, 10)}
    defaultValue={0}
    precision={0.5}
  />
```

"if you click on it to set a value - then again to null the stars --- when you focus off the field - like click elsewhere - it returns the old value "

Comment: Seems like it works fine to me...I can't recreate what you're saying

Comment: ok - if you click on it to set a value - then again to null the stars --- when you focus off the field - like click elsewhere - it returns the old value

Comment: Hmm that's odd...I can't really figure out why it's doing that either...

Comment: -- I thought it may be - because the value gets set to null - but then a number/string -- I think in the default version they have on material ui - there isn't such a feature - then we thought this empty stars on double click of the value was a feature - that then seemed busted -- so - it would be good to empty the stars on double click - as we have it as part of a filter system

Comment: it could be the precision thing -- and/or the position we put the {..input}